# What does var "header_row || 1" in App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I recently came over a spreadsheet with app script to collect keys of a doGet requested data.

There's a line in the code looks like this:

```
var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
```

What does this mean?

I checked out for "header_row" in App script Docs.
And "header_row" is also not a variable, as nothing is declared before.
And what does last character mean (..... || 1)?

Here is the bigger extract of the code, in case you need it:

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

```
  function doGet(e){
              var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
              var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
              var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
              var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
              // doing something here
                }
```

Comment: When `e.parameter.header_row` is not declared what is the value of `headRow`? Did you try checking the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
```

this line assumes that header of spreadsheet (name row) is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data i.e you can sned header_row parameter in GET/POST request to override default.

```
   .... ||1
```

this means to extract header from row no. 1, if you will do `..||2`row number 2 will be used for header.

Statement is simple, if expression before `||` is valid then that value will be assigned to the variable otherwise expression after `||`

Answer (score -1):

```
var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
```

this code means that e.parameter is an object and inside this object header_row property could be defined or not. If header_row property is defined and its value is not either *false, 0, "", or undefined* then its value will be assigned to **headRow** variable. Otherwise **headRow = 1**